# to check in in the region?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

Is is correct to say “You’ve just checked in in one of the best accommodation facilities in the region.”, mainly the part ‘to check in in ...’

Thanks a million.

Comment: It's okay. I would use "You've just checked in **at** one of..."

Comment: Some non-transitive MWVs sound better than others when followed by the corresponding preposition. 'He came in in a foul mood.' / ?'He ate in in Blackpool.' But you really want the transitive 'check into' here.

Answer (score 3):

While it is readable, I think a better phrasing would be "You’ve just checked into one of the best..." so that you avoid having the double proposition which can be tricky to parse. A quick Google n-gram puts it as much more commonly used than "in at" and "in in".

[image: check in ngram chart]

And from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check%20into):

> - check into
>
>   1. to check in at
>
>      > check into a hotel